# How do I "gzip" my responses in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, gzip

I know that this bit of code:

```
<?php if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); else ob_start(); ?>
```

will enable gzip. But, what is the correct way to apply this to all my Zend Frameworks `View`s and `Layout`s?

Comment: have you added the module via your php.ini?

Comment: The module is installed.

Comment: Did you consider letting your server handle this (e.g. with [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html))?

Comment: I have shared hosting (GoDaddy), and I'm not sure if they support it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of gzipping from PHP *(which means only your HTML generated content will be compressed)*, you could ask Apache to compress for you -- using its [**`mod_deflate`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) module.

Great advantage : it'll allow your server to compress HTML, of course... But also JS and CSS ; which means a huge gain for the users who have to download those when visiting your site.

*Note : if you are not using Apache, other web-servers have equivalents of `mod_deflate` ;-)*

Comment: Success! I was able to enable this using this guide: http://community.godaddy.com/groups/dedicated-linux/forum/topic/how-to-enable-gzip-compression-with-apache/

Comment: Actually better yet this one: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: Great :-) *(The link you posted in your second comment looks a bit like the one I put in my answer ^^ )*

Comment: Haha I must have opened it and then forgotten where it had come from... Thanks again!

Comment: Deflate is great! My 30KB page has been reduced to 6KB.

Comment: Yep ;-) And you can expect the same kind of ratio for JS and CSS, if you enable compression of those.

Comment: i'd like to add google page speed http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html

Answer (score 1):

This blog post should help you with what you need.

[Queued, Concatenated, and Gzipped Assets with the Zend Framework](http://blog.realmofzod.com/blog/2009/11/18/queued-concatenated-and-gzipped-assets-with-the-zend-framework/)

Answer (score 1):

That piece of code will still work on Zend Framework, it's what I use. Also, you don't need to check for the accept gzip header since ob_gzhandler() checks for that anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I was just confused about the right way of using it across Zend Framework.